# Contractions of product of symmetric positive definite matrix and symmetric matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, tensors

Assume $A$ is a $n\times n$ symmetric positive definite matrix and $B$ is a $n\times n$ symmetric matrix, and furthermore, $A$ satisfies the uniform ellipticity condition, i.e, there exists $\theta>0$ such that for any $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$ $x\cdot Ax\ge\theta|x|^2$. If we denote the inner product(or the contraction) of matrices by "$:$", then my question is:

1. Is $AB:BA\ge0$ always true?
2. Do we also have $AB:BA\ge\theta^2\|B\|^2$?

If we consider $AB:AB$, these two results are true.(1 is trivial, and for 2 we can write $AB:AB$ as $\sum_{i}(AB)_i\cdot(AB)_i=\sum_{i}AB_i\cdot AB_i$ )

However, $AB$ is not commutative in general, and so situation of $AB:BA$ should be essentially different from this.

I rewrite $AB:BA$ as $A:BAB^T$, which is a contraction of two symmetric positive definite matrices. I am not sure if this is enough to conclude 1.

Also, $AB:BA=\sum_{i}AB_i\cdot BA_i=\sum_{i}B^TAB_i\cdot A_i$ where $A_i$ and $B_i$ are $i$th column vectors. I am not sure if this is helpful either.

Thanks for any hint about proving or counterexamples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are talking about the usual inner product $X:Y=\operatorname{tr}(XY^T)$, the answers to both questions are yes. By a change of basis, we may assume that $A$ is a diagonal whose diagonal entries (which are also the eigenvalues) are $a_1\ge a_2\ge\ldots\ge a_n$. Then
$$
\operatorname{tr}((AB)(BA)^T)=\operatorname{tr}(ABAB)=\operatorname{tr}((A^{1/2}BA^{1/2})^2)=\|A^{1/2}BA^{1/2}\|_F^2=\sum_{i,j}a_ia_jb_{ij}^2\ge a_n^2\|B\|_F^2\ge0.
$$

Comment: Thanks, I basically agree with your argument. So if we take $A=Q^T\Lambda Q$ then $tr(ABAB)=tr(Q^T\Lambda QBQ^T\Lambda QB)=tr(\Lambda QBQ^T\Lambda QBQ^T)=tr(\Lambda D\Lambda D)$ where $D=QBQ^T$. Here $\Lambda=diag(a_1,\cdots, a_n)$ and $Q$ is orthogonal matrix. From your argument, we get $tr(ABAB)\ge a_n^2\|D\|^2\ge0$, hence 1 is true. I am wondering what can we say about the relationship between $\|D\|$ and $\|B\|$ so that we could conclude 2? Thanks!

Comment: Okay, I think I get it now. $\|D\|=\|B\|$ since $\|D\|^2=QBQ^T:QBQ^T=Q^TQBQ^T:BQ^T=BQ^T:BQ^T=B:BQ^TQ=B:B=\|B\|^2$. Thanks so much.